# Integer points on Elliptic Curves and Mordell-Weil Group

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Consider an elliptic curve $E:y^2=x^3+ax+b,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ with rank $r$ and trivial torsion group.(**The curve is quasi-minimal**,say,there are no primes $p$ such that $p^4\vert a$ and $p^6\vert b$)

Question:Suppose this curve has **many integer points**(say, more than $2^{r+1}$ integer points with $y>0$),is it possible to find $r$ integer points to generate the whole Mordell-Weil Group $E(\mathbb{Q})$?If not,is it possible to give an counterexample?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question : you want to extract a generating set from a big set of points? What if your big set of point is of the form P, 2P, 3P, 4P, etc?

Comment: @Julien Puydt:What I what to know is:if a elliptic curve with small rank and trivial torsion group has many integer points, is it possible to generate Mordell-Weil group ONLY BY INTEGER POINTS?I thought some Mordell curves might be good examples,say,the curve $y^2=x^3+17$ with rank is 2.

Comment: It is not always possible to generate the Mordell-Weil group with integral points. For example $E=517c1$ satisfies $E(\mathbf{Q})=\mathbf{Z}$ but a generator is $P=(85/4,513/8)$. See Cremona's tables http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/J.E.Cremona/book/fulltext/table2.pdf

Comment: @François Brunault：I use SAGE to calculate the integer points on $517c1$ and found no integer points on this curve. But my question is about a curve having many integer points.

Comment: I assume you have already done a search looking for counterexamples? How "far" (by conductor, say) have you looked?

Comment: That probably depends strongly on just what notion of "many" you use.
Too large, and it's true vacuously (at least under ABC) because the number of integral points on a curve of rank $r$ is bounded by $C^r$.  Too small, and you might find a curve with a subgroup of rank $r-1$ that has lots of integer points but also an $r$-th generator of such a large height that no equivalent integer point is expected.  Of course, once $r$ itself is large enough we don't know how to find a rank-$r$ curve even without any hypothesis on integer points.

Comment: @Noam: What you say is true under ABC, but using the word "vacuously" gives the impression that the implication is trivial. The fact that ABC implies `$#E(\mathbb{Z})\ll C^{rank E(\mathbb{Q}}$` (for quasi-minimal Weierstrass equations) is not so easy to prove. (At least, Marc Hindry and I didn't find it so easy!)

Comment: @Álvaro Lozano-Robledo:I have search for counterexmaple in mordell curve $y^2=x^3+k$ from a table on http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~KC2H-MSM/ec/eca1/index.htm. For $\vert k\vert \neg 1000$,no counterexample is found.($k=17,80,108$ are very interesting examples)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want is not possible in general.

Given a rank $x$ curve, using the group law find many rational points using only 1 generator. Then suitably scale $a$ and $b$ to get $E^'$ with the points integral and rank still $x$. The many known integral points will find only the used generator no matter how many they are.

The construction is similar to the first comment in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95120/number-of-x-such-that-m-x2-and-n-x2-are-both-squares).

Comment: @joro:Thanks for your answer. I have slightly changed my question.