# Reduction from factoring to solving Pell equation

Tags: factorization, diophantine-equations, nt.number-theory, cryptography

The paper [Polynomial-Time Quantum Algorithms for Pell's Equation and the Principal Ideal Problem](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~hallgren/pell.pdf) claims

> There are reductions from factoring to solving Pell’s equation, and from solving Pell’s
>   equation to solving the principal ideal problem [BW89b]

Can't find their reference [BW89b] on the internet and the extended abstract found doesn't address the issue.

What is the reduction from factoring to solving Pell equation?

The motivation is that solving the Pell equation $x^2-d y^2=1$ is trivial for $d$ a Fermat number. The period of the continued fraction for $\sqrt{d}$ is $1$.

**EDIT**

I am aware one gets the congruence $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod d$.

I don't consider this *reduction to factoring* because:

1. One can get the trivial $x \equiv \pm 1 \mod d$
2. Even if one gets non trivial factor it may be composite which is not complete factorization.

Other easy cases with short period of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{d}$ appear:

$$ d=a^2 \pm 1 $$
$$ d=a^2 \pm 4 $$
$$ d=a^2 \pm a $$
$$ d=a^2 \pm 4a $$ 
$$ d=b^2c^2 \pm b $$
$$ d=b^2c^2 \pm 2b$$

(the last two are due to Franz Lemmermeyer ).

[BW89b](ftp://www.hacktic.nl/pub/mirrors/Advances%20in%20Cryptology/HTML/PDF/C89/335.PDF) contains

> ...can be used to determine the regulator $R$ of $\mathcal{O}$ in polynomial time. One can then use the method described in [Schoof 8] to factor in polynomial time.

Schoof 8 might be [R.J. Schoof, Quadratic fields and factorization](http://cr.yp.to/bib/1982/schoof.html)

Andreas Stein repeats this claim: "Knowledge of the regulator, together with a technique due to Schoof can then in turn be used to factor $\Delta$" in [EQUIVALENCES BETWEEN ELLIPTIC CURVES AND REAL QUADRATIC CONGRUENCE FUNCTION FIELDS](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.2173&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> Does solving the Pell equation allows complete factoring of $d$? If yes how?

The motivation is finding factors of Fermat numbers would be interesting to me if possible.

Remotely related (using the regulator) is [Factoring $pq^2$ with Quadratic Forms: Nice Cryptanalyses](ftp://ftp.di.ens.fr/pub/users/pnguyen/Asia09.pdf)

Comment: I’d guess that you can use the solution to Pell’s equation to find a congruence of squares (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_of_squares) or something to that effect.

Comment: @Emil I tried this, but I got the trivial gcd()=n. If you think you can factor a Fermat number, I can give you the solutions of the Pell equation with $d$ the Fermat number with unknown factorization. I already know 2 solutions to $x^2=1 \mod d$ - they are $\pm 1$ but they are trivial. My pain is I get only trivial solutions so far.

Comment: I’m not claiming to know how the reduction works. However, if I may venture another guess, I’d expect $d=n+1$ to be more useful than $d=n$ ($n$ is the number to factorize).

Comment: @Emil If you can answer just answer the question, don't suggest wiki links.

Comment: Maybe the method works by choosing considering several $d = n \cdot k_i$, where $k_i$ is a random integer. A solution $(x, y)$ to the Pell equation yields $x \equiv 1 \pmod{d}$. Now either $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{d}$, or you got a factor. If there is a not too bad chance that for some $k$, you get a non-trivial solution, this would yield a factoring method. For example, if $n = 15$ and $k = 2$, then a fundamental solution for $d = 30$ is $(x, y) = (11, 2)$, and $gcd(x, n) = 5$ is a non-trivial factor.

Comment: Solving the Pell equation for d = a^2+1 is not tractable - it is trivial. 

Comment: You can't be bothered to write to the authors for a reprint, and you want us to tell you what is in a paper you have not seen?

Comment: Question also posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52871

Comment: @felix Thank you! Your method appears to work (including some cases with $k=1$). It loses tractability though.

Comment: BTW: I got this "method" when I looked at Emil's Wikipedia link; there was a link to the Continued Fraction Factorization Method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction_factorization), which is looking at the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{n k}$ for various $k$. From there on, it proceeds differently, but assuming one has a Pell solver oracle, working with a (fundamental) solution seemed like the obvious way to go.

Comment: And yes, it looses tractability, but that was not the point in [BW89] I assume, but just the existence of a Pell equation solver oracle which works not just for very special $d$, but for all $d$.

Comment: @felix Thank you. Is your method exactly the one described in the paper? btw, are  there other special $d$ for which Pell is tractable - experimentally $a^2+4$ may be.

Comment: @joro: I don't have that paper.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. The “extended abstract” IS the paper [BW89b], no other version exists. Here’s a copy: ftp://www.hacktic.nl/pub/mirrors/Advances%20in%20Cryptology/HTML/PDF/C89/335.PDF . The reduction is only mentioned in passing there, with reference to Schoof, Quadratic fields and factorization (http://cr.yp.to/bib/1982/schoof.html).

Comment: @Emil Thank you! Sorry I missed this.

Comment: The Schoof algorithm Emil referenced appears deterministic to me while felix's algorithm isn't...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had a fast method for solving Pell equations $x^2 - dy^2 =1$, you can factor numbers $N$ quickly: all you have to do is compute gcd$(x-1,d)$ for $d = N, 2N, 3N, \ldots$ until
you find a factor; if the factor is not prime, repeat the procedure.

Schoof showed that you don't have to know the actual solution of the Pell equation, but that the size of the regulator is sufficient. His method uses Shanks' idea of infrastructure
(see e.g. Jacobson and Williams, Solving the Pell Equation). By computing an ambiguous ideal
(if the norm of the fundamental unit is positive) he can then factor $d = N$; if the ambiguous ideal is trivial, do the same for $d = 3N$ etc.

Of course you cannot expect to factor Fermat numbers by simply writing down a solution of
the corresponding Pell equation. In the early days of factoring in the 1970s, Brillhart
and Morrison suggested using small multiples of $N$ if the period of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{N}$ is too small - this hasn't changed.

Comment: You said to repeat for $d=M,2N,3N,\dots$. How do we know the number of trials in logarithmic in $N$?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Lemmermeyer, reductions of Factoring to Pell's Equation do not seem to yield an efficient method to factor Fermat numbers, or at least, not in a straightforward fashion.

To see this better, let's answer in detail your **first question**: how to reduce Factoring to Pell's Equation? Although you have explicitly forbidden the approach I am going to follow, I think it is quite pedagogical to imitate Peter Shor's factorisation algorithm.

**Review:** Shor Algorithm to factor a composite number $d$

1. Classical part. Use that you can always get a factor of $d$ if you are able to find **non-trivial** solutions of $x^2=1\mod d$. Then either $gcd(x-1,d)$ or $gcd(x+1,d)$ is a factor of $d$.
2. Quantum part. Use the **order-finding** quantum algorithm to find an **non-trivial** number $a$ of even order. This number fulfils condition 1.
3. Repeat on smaller number until you end.

Steps 1. and 2. are explained very clearly in Nielsen & Chuang's book. [Wipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor_algorithm#Classical_part) has an article also.

**Reduction:** Factoring $d$ using Pell's Equation solver.

1. Classical part. Same as the previous one, making sure that the number to factor is not a square, i.e. $d\neq n^2$ (taking square roots of $d$ until you get a non-square $d'$).
2. Quantum part. Use Hallgreen's algorithm [[2](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1206035.1206039)][[3](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~amchilds/teaching/w11/l05.pdf)] (or a Pell's Equation solver) to find a non-trivial solution $(x_1, y_2)$ of $x^2-dy^2 = 1$, which is promised to exist as $d$ is not a square. The number $x_1$ fulfils condition 1 and you can obtain a factor of $d$ from it.
3. Repeat procedure.

**Second question:** can we factorise Fermat numbers?

As you have already highlighted, the above reduction does not give an efficient Fermat number factorisation routine:

1. There are no known classical algorithms to solve Pell's Equation, Order Finding or Period Finding (which is at the core of both), so we get stuck in step 2 in both cases.
2. If you try to restrict to Fermat numbers, using that you can solve Pell's Equation for them, this procedure does not work either unless the factors you find iteratively are also Fermat numbers.
3. Besides, I do not know of any efficient factorisation algorithms for general composite numbers which is not based on the same principles as Shor's. Therefore, in my view, finding a totally-different reduction that goes around  all problems present on the above method seems to be **quite tough question**.

I guess you know many of these obstacles to solve problem 2, but maybe this view of the problem can be illustrative.

Answer (score 0):

You may be aware of the following, and it probably doesn't answer all of your question. If $d > 0$ is both square-free and congruent to $2$ or $3 \pmod{4}$, and integers $x, y$ satisfy $x^2 - d y^2 = 1$ non-trivially with $y > 0$ and minimum among other solutions, then $\text{gcd}(2 x + 2, d)$ should be non-trivial. See Lemmermeyer's articles arXiv:math/0311306v1 and arXiv:math/0311310v1 . Examples: $(4, 1)$ satisfies $x^2 - 15 y^2 = 1$. $\text{gcd}(10, 15) = 5$. $(12, 1)$ satisfies $x^2 - 143 y^2 = 1$. $\text{gcd}(26, 143) = 13$.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose in $gcd(25,143)=13$, $25$ should be $26$ (the way you wrote it the gcd is $1$)

Comment: What about $\equiv 1 \mod 4$? Fermat numbers are this case.

Comment: Yes. I just edited that! $d \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ should be just as easy. I' ll have a think about. We need to turn $x^2 - d y^2 = 1$ into a Pell conic for $d \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. If $\Delta \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ then $x^2 - \Delta y^2 = 4$ is a Pell conic. In this case, take $\text{gcd}(x +2 ,\Delta )$.

Comment: $77 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. $(351, 40)$ is the least non-trivial solution to $x^2 - 77 y^2 = 1$. Small non-trivial points of the Pell conic $x^2 - 77 y^2 = 4$ are $(9, 1)$, $(79, 9)$, $(702, 80)$. The point $(351, 40)$ of the first equation corresponds to $(702, 80)$ of the second equation. $\text{gcd}(702 + 2, 77) = 11$. I think that I may occur that the point of the Pell conic obtained from the Pell equation is not the least non-trivial point, in which case from here it may occur that x+2 is a square, which would be a problem. I'll try a Fermat number next.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't always work. $(8589934593, 131072)$ satisfies $x^2 - (2^{2^5} + 1)) y^2 = 1$, $(17179869186, 262144)$ satisfies $x^2 - (2^{2^5} + 1)) y^2 = 4$. $\text{gcd}(17179869186 + 2, 2^{2^5} + 1) = 2^{2^5} + 1 $. Also, $(36893488147419103233, 8589934592)$ satisfies the Pell equation for $d = F_6$, $(73786976294838206466, 17179869184)$ satisfies the Pell conic. $\text{gcd}(73786976294838206466 + 2, 2^{2^6} + 1) = 2^{2^6} + 1$. It seems to have something to do with the fact that both fields have negative norm of fundamental unit.

Comment: Observe that $(2^{2^{n-1}})^2 - (2^{2^n} + 1) = -1$. If $d = 2^{2^n} + 1$ is square-free, then $(2^{2^{n-1}} , 1)$ is the fundamental solution to the Pell equation $x^2 - d y^2 = 1$. I think that the fundamental unit of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is $2^{2^{n-1}} + \sqrt{d}$, of norm equal to $-1$. Therefore $(2 \cdot (2^{2^{n-1}})^2 + 1, 2^{2^{n-1}+1})$ is the least non-triv. sol. to $x^2 - d y^2 = 1$, and $((2^{2^{n-1}+1})^2 + 2, 2^{2^{n-1}+2})$ is the least non-triv. sol. the Pell conic $x^2-d y^2 = 4$. Finally, $\text{gcd}((2^{2^{n-1}+1})^2 + 4, d) = d$.

Comment: People have said that solving $x^2 - d y^2 = 1$ should take more time than factoring, but I think that you have found a family of $d$ for which this might not be true.

Comment: Thank you. Strange, none of the articles I found listed exceptions. In addition Franz Lemmermeyer claims "solving the Pell equation ... is at least as hard as factoring $d$." here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50794/would-an-oracle-for-integral-points-on-elliptic-curves-be-a-factoring-oracle/50797#50797

Comment: http://www.ams.org/notices/200202/fea-lenstra.pdf and http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ant06.html are the references for solving Pell by already having the factors of $d$. Of course you would know this method. I have a feeling that the remark on the relative difficulty stems from that method of solution.

Comment: @Samuel if i understand correctly your approach might fail to give the **full factorization** giving 2 composite divisors...

Comment: I don't know how to obtain the full factorization of $d$ from the fundamental unit any related quadratic field, but possibly because I need to read more articles.

Comment: FRANZ LEMMERMEYER gives the tractable form $b^2 c^2 \pm 2 b$ and the factor $b$ is found (I don't see a closed form for it).


Comment: I'm a little confused as to precisely what you're referring to. I think that we're talking about the question: Assume that we have a fundamental unit of a quadratic field, since it is generally harder to find fundamental units than it is to factor (and I think this is because in at least two ways of solving Pell equations, the factoriation of $d$ is helpful and continued fractions take more time anyway ), can we use a fundamental unit to factor the discriminant of the quadratic field? I have seen Page 6 of arXiv:math/0311310v1, the example, and observed that partial factorization is possible.

Comment: I looked at [BW89b]. Towards the end it says "We show that a polynomial time solution of DLP can be used ti determine the regulator $\mathcal{R}$ of $\mathcal{O}$ in polynomial time. One can then use the method described in Schoof [8] to factor in polynomial time." DLP = discrete log problem, and the reference is R. J. Schoof, Quadratic fields and factorization in computational methods in number theory, Mathematische Centrum, 155, (1983), 235--286. I wasn't able to obtain this through my library.

Comment: Scanned copy of "Quadratic fields and factorization" by Schoof is available at: http://cr.yp.to/bib/1982/schoof.html. I am trying to understand the details.

Comment: I read enough to think this is not the same article as cited in [BW89b]. I found it interesting because it would suggest that perhaps rational points of Pell conics could be used to factor since they correspond to elements of the $2$-torsion subgroup of the narrow class group of binary quadratic forms of disc $\Delta$, the number to be factored.

Comment: Is the class number efficiently computable once you know the regulator with arbitrary precision?

Comment: I would use the class number formula, given the regulator. From memory, although I haven't studied the following, I thought Shanks baby-step giant-step algorithm is used to compute the class number. I have studied the class number with Pell conics, Pell surfaces, and elliptic curves. For Pell surfaces $S_n : x^2 + \sigma x y - m y^2 = z^n$, $\phi : S_n  \mapsto \text{Cl}^+(K)[n]$, where $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sigma + 4 m})$, $\sigma \in \\{ 0 , 1 \\}$. The kernel of $\phi $ is not always easy to compute.

Comment: @Samuel does the question make sense? Ideas about improving it? On one hand it is borderline fishing expedition, on the other reputable sources say otherwise.

Comment: @Joro : I have looked up the definition of tractable. I think that the dictionaries indicate that it means easy, whereas I think that in computational number theory it would mean in polynomial time? I would write the words "tractable and/or trivial". I recall seeing another article of Schoof's in the same place, which I saw on MathSciNet.

Comment: You say "short period". Are you refering to continued fractions? If so, that should be made clear also since there are several ways to solve Pell equations. See Question 48251.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Andreas Stein repeats this claim: "Knowledge of the regulator, together with a technique due to Schoof [9], can then in turn be used to factor $\Delta$" http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.2173&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Well, it must be true! It sounds like a good project to learn about
! I wish I had more time to think about it now. I need to finish my thesis.

Comment: Shanks sequence $S_n = (2^n+3)^2-8$ has short period of c.f. I read a claim that the class number of $S_n$ can be efficiently computed but can't find the paper " D.Shanks, Class number, a theory of factorization and genera, 1969 Number Theory Institute, Proc. Symbos. Pure Math, vol. 20, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence RI, 1971, pp. 415–440."