# On Pell's equation

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory

A post was made ([Reduction from factoring to solving Pell equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70913/reduction-from-factoring-to-solving-pell-equation)) seeking clarification to solving $$x^2-Dy^2=1$$ to factoring when $D>0$. An answer was posted stating that to factor $N$, it suffices to do trials of $D=N,2N,\dots$.

My questions:

**1.** How many such trials are needed?

**2.** What is complexity for each trial?

**3.** Is there an efficient method to solving equations of form $x^2+Dy^2=m$ when $D>0$?

Comment: Efficient method to (3) would give factoring algorithm, since it will compute the square root of $-D$ modulo $m$.

Comment: interesting! $1.$ Could you post as full answer? I did not know this. $2.$ Also supposing factoring is easy would it affect efficiency here?

Comment: Turbo, In (3) If you insist $D$ to be positive my reduction might need non-trivial changes...

Comment: corrected positivity. you are right $D<0$ in $(3)$ seems difficult even at $m=1$ and probably hopeless at general $m$.

Comment: I edited too. The main obstacle is that when D>0, there might too often be no solutions in my approach (if you find solution it will work).

Comment: Turbo, D<0 is definitely not hopeless for general m, assuming factoring oracle.

Comment: Asked this, related to your (3): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215309/is-this-factoring-algorithm-sufficiently-efficient-for-some-integers-of-special

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer to (2).

The smallest solution in some cases might be prohibitively large.

Check [this paper pp 3,4](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611209).

It uses negative Pell, but its solution is smaller that the wanted.

The paper shows the smallest solution might be exponential in $D$.

---

Efficient solution to (3) would give probabilistic factoring algorithm.

Computing square roots modulo composites gives probabilistic factoring,
since for composite $m$ if a root exists, in general there are more than two
by the chinese remainder theorem.

If you solve $r_1^2\equiv r_2^2 \pmod{m}$ and $r_1 \not \equiv \pm r_2 \pmod{m}$,
you know proper divisor.

Let $n$ be integer you want to factor. Pick random integer $d$
and set $D= (-d^2) \mod m$. Set $m=d^2+D$. Observe that $n$ divides $m$.

There is at at least one solution $(d,1)$ and there might be more.

Solutions modulo $m$ might give divisor of $n$, but not necessarily.

Solution means $x^2 \equiv -D y^2 \pmod{m}$. If $y$ is not invertible modulo $n$ this might divisor.

If it is invertible, you have found square root of $-D$ and already know one random.

If this fail to give divisor, of $n$ chose another $d$ and repeat.

Here is pari/gp toy implementation:

```
? n=11*17;d=52;D=-d^2%n;m=d^2+D;K=bnfinit(x^2+D);nor=bnfisintnorm(K,m)
%18 = [x + 52, -2*x + 49, -2*x - 49, -x + 52]
? t=49/2%n;[gcd(d-t,n),gcd(d+t,n)]
%19 = [11, 17]
? n=11*17;d=53;D=-d^2%n;m=d^2+D;K=bnfinit(x^2+D);nor=bnfisintnorm(K,m)
%26 = [x + 53, -4*x - 8, 4*x - 8, -x + 53]
? t=8/4%n;[gcd(d-t,n),gcd(d+t,n)]
%27 = [17, 11]
```

To solve it, you must factor both $D,m$, since similar argument applies for
composite $D$.

---

If you need this in practice, pari/gp's `bnfisintnorm()` does it,
but has additional to factoring overhead.

---

I believe even if factoring is easy this would be hard for negative $D$,
since it is a Pell equation for $m=1$ and it is not easy for prime $D$.

For $D$ positive likely it will be efficient assuming factoring oracle.

Comment: do you know answer to 1,2?

Comment: @Turbo Sorry, I don't know. Search the web for something like "complexity of computing fundamental units in quadratic number fields" (and variations). Wild guess: for 1, polynomial. For 2 subexponential, but the smallest solution might be prohibitively large...